# Can't delete a file via applescript due to path

Tags: applescript

I am trying to use a one line Applescript to delete a file in a known directory - but I can't get it to recognize the directory:
    osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to delete (files of entire contents of folder "/Folder1/folder2" whose name is "MyFile.txt")'

but I get the following error:

```
29:183: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t get folder "/Folder1/folder2". (-1728)
```

I have also tried:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to delete (files of entire contents of folder "folder2" of folder "Folder1" whose name is "MyFile.txt")'
```

But had similar results - it couldn't find Folder1

I want the script to work across computers, so I don't know what a disk name would be.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tell application "Finder" to delete (files of entire contents of folder (POSIX file "/Folder1/folder2") whose name is "MyFile.txt")
```